# Speed up asset compilation and app performance via $RAILS_ROOT/tmp on a ramdisk?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am curious as to whether anyone has seen any positive results from creating a `tmpfs` filesystem and mounting it as the `$RAILS_ROOT/tmp` folder on production applications, particularly on the deployment front?

We have been running TorqueBox and asset compilation takes a considerable amount of time at present.  We were brainstorming and the thought crossed our minds of using `tmpfs` for the tmp folder and I was curious as to what kinds of gains we might see from that in both asset compilation and perhaps general performance if anyone has tried something similar previously.

Comment: You could link it with `ln -s /tmp ./tmp` instead. Precompiling takes about 25m for my current project. You can find out how fast it will go with `cp -r myapp /tmp/; cd /tmp/myapp; time rake assets:precompile`